# WPF tab navigation within dynamically generated controls using DataTemplateSelector

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I thought it might be simple but even after so much effort still unable to add tab navigation support for dynamically generated controls inside `TreeListView`, using `ControlTemplateSelector`, based on item binding.

The controls are generating correctly but the tab navigation is not working within them, I even tried using `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"` and other options but no luck.

What could be the missing pieces?

**XAML (Updated):**

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Style="{x:Null}">
    <TabItem Header="Schema">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>                
            <fsx:TreeListView ItemsSource="{Binding TestSession.TreeViewItems}" IsTabStop="False" 
                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
                <fsx:TreeListView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <fsx:TreeListViewExpander/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="400"
                        CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource EntityItemControlTemplateSelector}" />
                </fsx:TreeListView.Columns>
            </fsx:TreeListView>
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <ListBox Grid.Row="2" IsTabStop="True" />
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

**DataTemplates:**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxControlTemplate">
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Value, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Width="200" Margin="1" 
                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="{Binding TabIndex}"></TextBox>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxControlTemplate">
    <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding Value}" IsThreeState="False" 
                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="{Binding TabIndex}"></CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DateControlTemplate">
    <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" Margin="1" SelectedDate="{Binding Value}"
                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="{Binding TabIndex}"></DatePicker>
</DataTemplate>
```

**DataTemplateSelector:**

```
public class ControlTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DateControlTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate CheckBoxControlTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TextBoxControlTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        DataTemplate template = null;

        var x = item as IEntityItemValue;
        var entityItem = x?.Item as IEntityItemDef;

        if (entityItem != null)
        {
            switch (entityItem.Type)
            {
                case DataType.Boolean:
                    template = CheckBoxControlTemplate;
                    break;
                case DataType.Date:
                    template = DateControlTemplate;
                    break;                  
                case DataType.String:
                    template = TextBoxControlTemplate;
                    break;                    
            }
        }

        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you tried to set KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"? Are you sure it's a problem of DataTemplateSelector, does it work without?

Comment: Could you please suggest where to use KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation?

Comment: I'm not familiar with TreeListView, but for beginning I would try to set KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue" for all elements(up to TreeListView), which contain your controls you want to tab through and set IsTabStop="False" for GridColumn and GridCell

Comment: Still no luck ... i have however updated the XAML section to show more details

Comment: Make the same for GridViewColumn andGridViewCell. Just implement it as styles in TreeListView's resources.